# Find max date in multiple columns in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have csv file source and it have 5 date columns . I need to create a new column which will have the latest date after comparing  all the 5 columns .

Expample :

source 
[![cust id  dt1 dt2 dt3 dt4 dt5 
101][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46QR3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46QR3.png)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of ways that it can be done.

The first is using pure SSIS tasks and data flows. Based on your source data, the easiest approach I can think of would be to use an `Unpivot Transformation` followed by an `Aggregate Transformation` to get the values you need. Un-pivot on `DT1`, `DT2`, `DT3`, `DT4` and `DT5` and then aggregate over the date column and group by the `CustID` field. This would achieve what you need.

I don't have a copy of SSIS in front of me right now, but you can find the documentation for [Unpivot Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/unpivot-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) and [Aggregate Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/aggregate-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) on Microsoft Docs.

Alternatively, if the data is in a table (or can be put into a table), then you could just write a SQL script and call that via an [Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2017) to do the unpivot and aggregation for you like this:

```
 SELECT CustID, MAX([Date]) AS [Date]
   FROM (SELECT CustID, DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5) AS p
UNPIVOT ([Date] FOR [Dates] IN (DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5)) u;
```

Then you can just return the row set back into SSIS if you need to. Either method would be fine for such a small data set but test them both and see which one performs better and is easier to maintain.